# I'm having trouble applying a bevel to curve

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel

I am fairly new to Blender, and I'm having trouble with applying an object-bevel to a Bezier curve.  I've had success in the past, extruding one object around the contour of another, and I have even tested applying the bevel to a simpler object in my current .blend file, and it works, but when I try to extrude the circle object around the curve of the saddle-shaped object, the saddle-shaped object just disappears in a weird way.

Here is a shot of the three objects in my setup: on the left is the saddle-like curve I'd like to give a thickened, circular cross-section, and I want to use the small circle in the middle to do it.  The square on the right is just there for debugging.

[image]

In this next photo, I've successfully performed the bevel operation on the square to the right -- you can see it took the bevel operation, and now has a diameter of 8mm.

[image]

However, when I try to apply the same circular bevel to the saddle-shape, the saddle-shape just disappears, though I can see weird, flickery traces of the old shape:

[image]

I've made sure the scales of the objects are compatible, and haven't come up with anything in searches.  I'd really appreciate anyone's help with this!

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've figured it out: I just had some vertices which were too close together.  I'd already tried merging by distance at 1.0 mm, but it required a merge radius of 2.1 mm before it would finally take that bevel.

Cheers.

Comment: For a round bevel you don't need a circle, just do it in the geometry of the square directly with the bevel settings on the geometry controls of the curve. Then give the object smooth shading.

Comment: susu, thank you for your suggestion.  I will try that next time :)